# If I lose a Zoombini, or mess up a puzzle, can I get them back?

Tags: zoombinis

Sometimes when you make enough mistakes on a puzzle, you can lose Zoombinis. Is there any way I can get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can get back any Zoombini you lose along the way.

Normally, the game will take any Zoombini that is "lost", and take them back to the last checkpoint you passed. Then, when you come back to that checkpoint in the next game, you can then re-add them to the group (if you have space), or swap them out for other Zoombinis to try and get your whole group to have a similarity (same nose colour, same hair, etc.) to gain an advantage on the next section of the game.

Alternatively, you can quit and reload the game. Then, when you choose your in-game profile, it will load the puzzle you were currently on, with all the Zoombinis you came in with, as if you hadn't done the puzzle yet.

**Note:** the puzzle *may* change if you reload the game, depending on which one it is.

Comment: I can not confirm if they got this fixed for android or iPhone, but on computer, this led to the possibility that you would have Zombinis left, but not enough to initiate specific actions required to save them. IIRC, if you needed on an odd number (or something similar), a few remaining Zombinis could get stuck.